# Symfony2 Slow on Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, symfony, virtualbox

For some reason my Symfony2 install is super slow when served from a VM running Ubuntu 12.04 on VirtualBox in development mode (app_dev.php).  In production mode its fast (no problem here).

When the app is served outside of the VM using MAMP, I get the following times in the profiler:

Total Time: 337 ms

Initialization Time: 158 ms

When the app is served from the VM, I get the following times:

Total Time: 2069 ms

Initialization Time: 1908 ms

Xdebug is enabled in for MAMP, but disabled on the VM (it was twice as slow with xdebug enabled).

Any idea why it is so much slower on the VM in dev mode?

**Update:**

It is now taking upwards of 40 seconds to serve a request.  It starts off at 2 seconds, then takes longer and longer each time.  Eventually, the VM locks up and freezes.  I saw a messge in the terminal saying that apache is out of memory (apache, not php).  Currently the VM has 1gb of memory available (more than enough IMO).

I'm not using shared folder of any kind.

**Update:**

For some reason it just started working properly again.  I was even able to scale it back to 1 CPU and its working great.  I enabled xdebug again and it went from 200ms load times to 800ms load times (acceptable in development IMO).  My question now is, "Why would something like this happen?"  I didn't do anything to make to start being slow, and then all of the sudden it is fast again.  Could there be something wrong with my Mac?  I'm running Ubuntu server 12.04 (64-bit).

Comment: No shared folders, I'm uploading files to it via FTP.

Answer (score 1):

1. If code is on the Windows and it's samba shared to Ubuntu it will be super slow
2. When I host Symfony2 on Amazon EC2 it needs to be c1-medium-highcpu because on normal its kinda slow and its choking on CPU. Give to your VM another CPU core and some more ram.

Spec of Amazon medium-highcpu

> 1.7 GB of memory
>   5 EC2 Compute Units (2 virtual cores with 2.5 EC2 Compute Units each)
>   350 GB of instance storage
>   32-bit or 64-bit platform
>   I/O Performance: Moderate
>   EBS-Optimized Available: No
>   API name: c1.medium

1. Turn on the APC Cache and use in memory caching. If the symfony class cache is on HDD it's slow.
2. If all 3 above doesn't compare php.ini line by line.

Comment: I'll check the CPU settings for the VM and see what happens.

Comment: I gave the VM 100% CPU and 2 CPU's (cores)!  Still no joy.  I checked what was going on using 'top' and during the request apache bounces between 75%-100% usage of the CPU and hovers at around 5% memory usage.

Comment: Try to enable in `BIOS` CPU virtalisation features. They may be disabled. As an alternative you can install the ubuntu 12.04 server version without any X11 or first of all run the Unity in 2d mode. Unity needs a lot of resources. If you can't handle ubuntu without GUI. Try to install xubuntu 12.04 (ubuntu with xfce - light wegiht desktop good enough for single core pentiums).

Comment: have yo configured the APC cache?
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/performance.html

Comment: I'm currently running Ubuntu server.  I'll try the bios settings.  I don't want to have to use APC.  I know it will run faster w it, but it shouldn't have 40 second request times without APC.